# Pinterest-like navigation in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-animation, pinterest

I'm using a `recyclerview` in my android app which holds a large number of items. when the user clicks one of the items, I want to implement a navigation like `Pinterest` app:

[image]

I have already tried to achieve such navigation by scaling the recyclerview and then adding another fragment below the scaled image, but since it is actually a tricky solution, it has lots of difficulties and problems. is there any official/logical way to achieve this navigation in android?

Comment: I assume you are launching an activity when clicked on an item. You can use various activity transition animations in order to achieve that. Here's a helpful link - https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1880

Comment: Yep, no need for fancy tricks. It's just a transition with shared elements. Anroid has an API for that. [This is the official guide for that](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity). It also contains a link to an [example project](https://github.com/android/animation-samples/tree/master/ActivitySceneTransitionBasic).